# n3-Charts line-chart(Angular JS), not able to find custom click event handling to drill down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using n3-Charts line charts in Angular js application. My requirement is when user clicks on a point in line or on 'bar' I need the details at that point, so that I can do some custom stuff with that info. Could not find click event handling related documentation @ https://github.com/n3-charts/line-chart. Please provide me the pointers or examples.